# tabulator rowFormatter find all columns via Title ending with pattern

Tags: javascript, dom, tabulator

- Tabulator 5.1.0
- VisualStudio 2022 Community

The data is dynamic for column names and data after the first 3 columns
So columns 1, 2, & 3 would be like "Switch", "Node", "Total"
All other columns are dynamically added via dynamically creating the column definitions. There may be from 1 to 500 more columns

In the rowFormatter function, I can get the row data and the row DOM element

```
        var cellTable = row.getCell("Switch");
        if (cellTable.getValue() == "showBase") {
            var rowData = row.getData();
            var rowDOMElement = row.getElement();
            var columnList = [code to get columns like *_T]
            for(var c in columnList ) {
               * find non _T column (nonTc)
               * make c hidden
               * make nonTc visible
            }
        }
```

I need to find all row DOM element columns ending in a pattern like "_T"

- any column with that suffix will have a matching column without the suffix.

ie
A row with a column named ABCD_EF_T will also contain the column ABCD_EF. By default any ABCD_EF column is hidden, and any ABCD_EF_T column is visible.

**The goal in the code above, is to make any such ABCD_EF column visible, and any ABCD_EF_T hidden**

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/ovdL1r5x/1/)

Comment: @DoubleH thank you, but that affects all columns in the table. In rowFormatter, I'm trying to affect *just* the active row. The previous or next row may be required to show the COLUMN-BASENAME+ "_T" version of the data. And perhaps 'visibility' changes can also be achieved with column width updates - ie set width of the COLUMN-BASENAME to 200 and the width of the COLUMN-BASENAME+ "_T" version to zero...  So I need to find the names of the columns as a list & don't need the column cells because I can iterate the string array of columns and use row.getCell(colArray[i]) to get it to affect widths

Comment: I have update my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/ovdL1r5x/3/)   You can switch visibility by clicking the rows